# opencart отправка get form

Tags: form, get, opencart

хочу отправит форму при отправке get url получается: `домен.ру/opencart/index.php?ppath=массив`

```
<form name="form" action="/opencart/index.php?route=search/search&q=<?=$q?>&data-key=ppath" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ppath[]" value="54154:654" />text<br />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

а надо `домен.ру/opencart/index.php?route=search/search&q=<?=$q?>&data-key=ppath&ppath=массив` то что указанно в `action` почему так получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут вот](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) написано:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

т.е. при get методе отправки данных user agent видит ? в action формы и после неё всё перезаписывает данными инпутов. Так что передавайте все параметры при get методе инпутами:

```
<form name="form" action="/opencart/index.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="route" value="search/search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="<?=$q;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data-key" value="ppath" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ppath[]" value="54154:654" />text<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

Что на выходе склеит ваш url в `домен.ру/opencart/index.php?route=search/search&q=<?=$q?>&data-key=ppath&ppath=массив`

З.Ы. Вдохновлён [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116019/submitting-a-get-form-with-query-string-params-and-hidden-params-disappear) ответом.

Comment: Спасибо помогло.